# Python Urwid Keystrokes

Tags: python, urwid

Good evening everybody,

I have an application built using Python Urwid library. It has several fields and hence takes quite some time to go to the bottom of the application using "Page Down" or "Down" keys. I'm just wondering if there is any keystrokes operations which directly take the cursor to the bottom. 
Something similar to this:

```
class SimulationView(urwid.WidgetWrap):       (line 6)
{ 
def get_main_frame(self):                     (line 127)
buttons_box = urwid.ListBox(buttons_walker)   (line 148)
errors_box = urwid.ListBox(self.errors_content) (line 155)
sim_listbox = urwid.ListBox(self.sim_list_content)(line 158)

body = urwid.Pile([(6, buttons_box),('weight', 4, sim_listbox),
                       ('weight', 1, errors_box)])
frame = urwid.Frame(body, header=header)
     return frame


def keypress(self, size, key): 

   If key is "a": 
      # command to take the cursor to the bottom of the application
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That code isn't syntactically valid (it has brackets and line information that doesn't belong there -- can you pls post a small version that demonstrates the problem in a way that we can run it?

Comment: Problem is, i'm running this 350 lines of code from one more main code which is also long. It's difficult to post the running code. Is there any other ways i can give more details?

Comment: The best way would be to create a new separate program, containing the minimal structure of the app (only the main widgets + examples), the so called [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any equivalent mapping for that for the default widgets, if only because each app would probably have a different concept of what "the bottom" is.

What exactly do you mean by "the bottom"? Is there a widget that is always there, for which you want to give focus?

The [container widgets](http://urwid.org/manual/widgets.html#container-widgets) have a writable `focus_position` attribute that you can use to change focus, here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import print_function, absolute_import, division
import urwid


def global_input(key):
    if key in ('q', 'Q', 'esc'):
        raise urwid.ExitMainLoop()
    elif key == 'page down':
        # "bottom" is last button, which is before footer
        pile.focus_position = len(pile.contents) - 2
    elif key == 'page up':
        # "top" is the first button, which is after footer
        pile.focus_position = 1
    elif key in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
        pile.focus_position = int(key)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    footer = urwid.Text('Footer')
    pile = urwid.Pile([
        urwid.Padding(urwid.Text('Header'), 'center', width=('relative', 6)),
        urwid.Button('Button 1'),
        urwid.Button('Button 2'),
        urwid.Button('Button 3'),
        urwid.Button('Button 4'),
        urwid.Padding(footer, 'center', width=('relative', 20)),
    ])
    widget = urwid.Filler(pile, 'top')
    loop = urwid.MainLoop(widget, unhandled_input=global_input)
    loop.run()
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer!. The bottom i'm referring to is similar to the last page of a book. In my case, things are not piled. There are different container widgets, hence i want to change the focus from one container to another. How to do this?

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like you need a `find_bottom` that knows about the layout and will get you the container and position for whatever is the bottom. Can you share a bit more about your current code? At this point, it seems more of a matter of software design than urwid. :) You might consider looking into [signals](http://urwid.org/reference/signals.html)

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement!. Sorry for the delayed response. As i'm new to this, it takes time for me to try out different things and come up with right questions. At this point, problem is not to switch between different containers because there is only one container which is tooo long(like only one of the pages in the book is too long). In this long container, different things are piled as in your example. Problem is, urwid.MainLoop() is not inside the class in which all these containers are included.

Comment: Also, i cound't use "keypress" function as all these are inside some other class. I don't see the possibility of using "Super" either, as all these things are inside a child class which is inherited from "urwid.WidgetWrap"

Comment: @spectre no worries, nothing to apologize for -- these things take time! Tbh i'm not following everything you're saying. You said something about a page of a book -- I assume you're working on an book reading app? That sounds super interesting! Can you maybe open a new question for each specific problem that you have (for example, handling the long page, what problem exactly does it cause)?